# Trying to solve a Simple RPG game

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a task that's a bit too much for me. The idea is to have a simple RPG game with the parent class (AllPlayers) and a subclass PlayerOne. I'm struggling with the calling of the player profession and his inventory system. I need to print how many coins the player has in its pocket, too.

**MAIN:**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String username;
    public static PlayerOne player;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Choose your name: ");
        username = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Choose your profession: \n" +
                "Press 1 for a knight class\n" +
                "Press 1 for a rider class\n" +
                "Press 1 for a mage class");


        player = new PlayerOne(username);
        player.displayPlayerOne();
        player.displayPlayerInventory();
        player.displayPocketCoins();
        player.displayPlayerProfession();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I set the getters and setters but that's the farthest I have gone so far. Can you provide me with some clues on how to

- call the profession in the main?
- call the inventory in the main?
  I guess I'll figure out how to call coins in the main later, it will be quite the same as with profession and inventory.
  Thank you!

**AllPlayers (SUPERCLASS)**

```java
    public class AllPlayers {

    protected String name;
    private int level;
    private int health;
    private int damage;

    public AllPlayers(String name, int level, int health, int damage) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
        this.health = health;
        this.damage = damage;
    }
}
```

And here is the player class:

```java
public class PlayerOne extends AllPlayers{

    private String [] inventory;
    private int coins;
    private String [] professions;


    public PlayerOne(String name) {
        super(name, 1, 20,5);
        this.professions = getProfessions();
    }

    public void setProfessions(String[] professions) {
        this.professions = professions;
    }

    public String[] getProfessions() {
        return this.professions;
    }

    public void setCoins() {
        this.coins = coins;
    }

    public int getCoins() {
        return coins;
    }

    public void setInventory() {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public String[] getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public void displayPlayerOne() {
        System.out.println("Your name is " + super.name);
    }

    public void displayPlayerInventory() {
        inventory[0] = "knife";
        inventory[1] = "sword";
        inventory[2] = "spear";
        inventory[3] = "potion";
    }

    public void displayPocketCoins() {
        coins = 50;
    }

    public void displayPlayerProfession() {
        professions[0] = "knight";
        professions[1] = "rider";
        professions[2] = "mage";
    }
}
```

Comment: What would "calling" the professions look like? What does it mean? `professions` is an array. What does calling an array mean for you?

Comment: Hi there, Federico! I'd like to call it (is that a correct term? English is my second language) with the user input. The user should input the number to choose between the knight, the rider, and the mage. I hope my answer is making sense to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> call the profession in the main?

Well, you already have the type declaration `PlayerOne player;` so just call `player.getProfessions()` and use the array.

> call the inventory in the main?

Just the same: `player.getInventory()`.

However, note that your design is somewhat flawed (although since you're a beginner don't bother too much). The class name `PlayerOne` indicates any other player (e.g. `PlayerTwo`) would be different, but that's probably not the case. Also, `AllPlayers` doesn't actually indicate a *class*, but it looks more like a collection.

You might think about changing your class names, e.g. assuming `AllPlayers` will be used for NPCs as well, you could name it `Character` while the class for players is called `Player`. Doing this you could have multiple players if needed: `Player playerOne`, `Player playerTwo` etc.